# How do I save a chrome-extension screenshot to a file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension for schools (So the teacher can monitor what the students are doing on theyr chromebooks).
I've used the `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab`string and there I met my new problem:
**How do I save that screenshot to a file?** (must hapen in background, else student can stop it)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of course you can. It is very interesting how this can be done.

> The **manifest.json** file:

```
{    
    "name": "Screenshot Extension",        
    "manifest_version": 2,     
    "version": "1.0",     
    "description": "Save web page screenshots to image files by one click",     
    "background": {     
        "persistent": false,     
        "scripts": ["background.js"]     
    },     
    "content_scripts": [     
     {     
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "matches" : ["<all_urls>"]                
     }

    ],     
    "browser_action": {     
        "default_icon": "extension_icon.png",     
        "default_title": "Screenshot of this page"     
    },     
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "<all_urls>"]     
}
```

> The **content.js** file:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {    
    if (msg.ready === "ready") {
        if (confirm('Do you want to have a capture of this screen?')) {
            sendResponse({download : "download"});
        }
    }   
});
```

> The **background.js** file:

```
var screenshot = {
    content : document.createElement("canvas"),
    data : '',

    init : function() {
        this.initEvents();
    },

    saveScreenshot : function() {
        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function() {
            var canvas = screenshot.content;
            canvas.width = image.width;
            canvas.height = image.height;
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

            // save the image
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.download = "download.png";
            link.href = screenshot.content.toDataURL();
            link.click();
            screenshot.data = '';
        };
        image.src = screenshot.data; 
    },

    initEvents : function() {
        chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {
                format : "png",
                quality : 100
            }, function(data) {
                screenshot.data = data;

                // send an alert message to webpage
                chrome.tabs.query({
                    active : true,
                    currentWindow : true
                }, function(tabs) {
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {ready : "ready"}, function(response) {
                        if (response.download === "download") {
                            screenshot.saveScreenshot();
                        }
                        else {
                            screenshot.data = '';
                        }
                    });
                }); 

            });
        });
    }
};

screenshot.init();
```

- The **`background.js`** controls the logic of the extension, whereas
  **`content.js`** interacts with web pages. They send messages to
  communicate with each other.
- If you want to make your extension work for all web sites, you have to set   the permission `<all_urls>`

Comment: Thank you so much! You have saved me a lot of time, It is working just as I wanted.

Comment: Glad to help :)