# I want to grab a screenshot or logo of a website with only its URL

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a chrome extension and I want to mimic how browsers are able to grab a screenshot or logo of a website by only its link. You usually see it when you open a new tab. I'm using json, javascript, css and html.

Below is the examples of those.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/upxrr.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKMpb.png)

I've tried to search for  within the Chrome API Documentation, but I couldn't find anything on it. I've also tried to use iFrames, but they are extremely insufficient and they don't resize well on a smaller display.

Comment: Have you looked at this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952120/how-do-i-save-a-chrome-extension-screenshot-to-a-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I save a chrome-extension screenshot to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952120/how-do-i-save-a-chrome-extension-screenshot-to-a-file)

Comment: @PauloSantos sadly it doesn't, what I'm specifically looking for is having cells that contain the thumbnail/preview or logo of the website with only the link.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an specific use case for that?, if not i think you could save a lot of time implementing it yourself.
You could import a custom png or svg file and wrap it with a  tag

```
<a href="link">
 <img src={yourImgSrc} width={} height={}></img>
</a>
```

Comment: I don't have access to an image only the link itself to the website. I'm grabbing the URL from the user input.